# Unsatisfiedlinkerror native method not found

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, runtime-error

Now I am getting the error:

```
unsatisfiedLinkerror native method not found.2-04 07:16:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1962): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.hellocplusplus.MainActivity.camera:()I.
```

pls help me

My c++ code:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>



#include <jni.h>




#include <opencv/highgui.h>





using namespace cv;



/************************************************************************************************************
**
***********************************************************************************************************/



extern "C"{

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_hellocplusplus_MainActivity_camera
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_hellocplusplus_MainActivity_camera
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
{

            VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

            if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
            {
                //cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
                return -1;
            }

            namedWindow("MyVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a windowcalled "MyVideo"

            //Show continous video on the output window
            while (1)
            {
                Mat frame;

                bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

                if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
                {
                    //cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

                if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
                {
                    //cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return (jint) 0;
        }

}
```

My java code:

```
package com.example.hellocplusplus;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;

import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;



import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;



import android.os.Bundle;




import android.app.Activity;




import android.util.Log;




import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static String TAG="OpenCVImageProcessing";
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    System.loadLibrary("nativegray");
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };
    public native int camera();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     camera();
        //i=camera();
        //System.out.println(i);
      //  camera1();
    }
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }







    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does .so file in `libs` folder? Android application libraries in "libs" project folder are written onto /data/data/[package_name]/lib folder. During runtime they are loaded from this location if needed. Check http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE

Comment: yes .so file is in libs folder. but its not in Android Application /data/data/[packge_name]/lib folder.I think it will take from opencv manager.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, your "nativegray" so was not loaded, when you called the `camera()` code.

you cannot call any opencv code in onCreate(), since the opencv so's ( and your own, too ) only got loaded, once mLoaderCallback finishes, which gets called from onResume()

and then , your c++ code there will *never* work.

you can't call namedWindow(), imshow() or waitKey() on android (E_NOKEYBOARD), 
and a while(1) loop is not legit, since it will stall your Activity.

Comment: I think you are right @berak any link you will provide so to correct the c++ code. when i call mLoaderCallback in on create before the camera native method call its showing the same error

Comment: you will have to move your camera() code to onCameraViewStarted() or similar.